# Allow un-authenticated users to Write but not read any other child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So I 've a application where users are able to write in my database(ONLY during SIGNUP). I want to grant them read/write access to JUST their child node and not my whole database. Currently, an un-authenticated user has full write access to my whole database node. This is my Firebase user node-

```
"users" : {
    "-LAQxFS_GNA-xKewLYgDe" : {   
      "name" : "XYZ"
      "phone" : "988900000"
    },
"-LAffLlvl9ZTm-D1FMS8" : {
      "name" : "XXYYZZ"
      "phone" : "32223333"
    },
```

....and so on

Here, i want this child user "**LAQxFS_GNA-xKewLYgDe**" to only access his node without any access to other child nodes.

Here's my *rules*

```
  {
  "rules": {
   "messages":{
       ".read":true,
         ".write":true
     }
  , "books":{
     ".read":true,
     ".write":true  
   },
    "aTime":{
     ".read":true, 
     ".write":true  
    },
     "users":{
      ".read":false,
      ".write":true
     } 

  } 
}
```

PS: I've my own custom signup page where users enter their name and phone number. This info is saved in "users" node.

Comment: Yes, but its for "authenticated" users only having a unique uid @Andre Kool

Comment: So you are not using firebase authentication?

Comment: I think what you want is anonymous authentication.  Let the user only access that node using the standard way of doing things (in the docs).  When the user onboards, then you upgrade the anonymous post (also in the docs)

Comment: No authentication..user has direct access to app contents..  @AndréKool

Comment: In that case you should include how you "authenticate" your users. Also make sure you use the correct tags on your question and make sure to read the tag descriptions.

Comment: Firebase Anonymous Authentication is done silently in the background without the user's knowledge or explicit consent.  Think of it as generating a unique ID or cookie.  As long as that client/browser has the cookie, it can write to any node that is locked to that unique ID.